# Azure VM Disk Driver Error

Tags: azure, virtual-machines, drivers

we are experiencing a strange issue with our Azure VMs.
In the Windows Event Log we get the following Issue:

> Event-ID 11
>
> The driver detected a controller error on
>   \Device\Harddisk0\DR0.

Has anyone ever had this? Is there something we can do / check from our side?

What we have already done:
- Created an Azure Support Request
- Checked the Metrics Data Disk Queue Depth (SUM) wich never gets over 1
- Checked the Logs for other irregularities

We did not change anything when this error started showing up or before.
Hope anyone has some insights.

If we get to a resolution I'll submit an Answer here.

Thanks in advance

Best Michael

Edit:

Google search turned up nothing except for this unresolved thread:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fbb890f6-188f-4ac6-afc2-668006676c3c/azure-vm-disk-error?forum=windowsazureonlinebackup

Edit 2:
We also checked Azure Status:
https://status.azure.com/en-us/status# no known outage on our region.

<strike>A restart of the VM resolved the strange RDP behavior we were experiencing with the issue, the Driver Error persists.</strike>

Edit 3: The RDP issue from today is absolutely not related, this was an error in the analysis by a colleague of mine.